# Get current route action name from middleware in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a middleware like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Contracts\PermissionsHandlerInterface;
use Closure;

class PermissionsHanlderMiddleware {

    public $permissionsHandler;

    function __construct(PermissionsHandlerInterface $permissionsHandler) {
        $this -> permissionsHandler = $permissionsHandler;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        $routeAction = $request->route()->getActionName();

        /*
         do some operations
        */

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

but `$request->route()` always returns `null`, I think its because the router hasn't been dispatched with the request.

**Note:** I added my middleware to `Kernal.php` global middlewares to run before each request as the following

```
protected $middleware = [
        .
        .
        .
        'App\Http\Middleware\PermissionsHanlderMiddleware',
    ];
```

I want to get route action name before the execution of `$next($request)` to do some permission operations. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot get the route action name if the router has not yet been dispatched. The router class has not yet done its stuff - so you cannot do `$router->request()` - it will just be null.

If it runs as routeMiddleware as `$routeMiddleware` - then you can just do  `$router->request()`

You can get the URI string in the middleware before the router has run - and do some logic there if you like: `$request->segments()`. i.e. that way you can see if the URI segment matches a specific route and run some code.

Edit:

One way I can quickly think of is just wrap all your routes in a group like this:

```
$router->group(['middleware' => 'permissionsHandler'], function() use ($router) {
            // Have every single route here
});
```

Comment: i need `actionName` because i pass it to Doctine SimpleAnnotationReader to get some annotation, so `$request->segments()` will not help me. Is there any other way to execute my middleware in all requests to check permissions.

Comment: There is one way - see my editted answer. There might be a way to manually call a middleware object while the router is booting - but I cant think of it as this stage - I'll play around with it tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I did in my project:

```
...
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    DB::beginTransaction();
    $nextRequest = $next($request); //The router will be dispatched here, but it will reach to controller's method sometimes, so that we have to use DB transaction.
    $routeName = $request->route()->getRouteName();
    if ($checkPassed) {
        DB::commit();
        return $nextRequest;
    } else {
        DB::rollback();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also fine.

```
$request->path(); // path
$request->route()->getName()//name of the route
```