# CSRF Token expires in file upload form in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, csrf, laravel-5

I have a file upload form with a hidden field for the *csrf token*. Everything works just fine when the file is small <1MB, but when I upload large files the request would take more time and it seems the token expires because I get a `TokenMismatchException`, any workaround for this? Thanks

This is my form:

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ $user->id }}" />

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="file">File</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" />
        </div>
</form>
```

And this is my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();

    $user     = User::findOrFail ($request->get('user_id'));
    $filePath = "/app/files/$user->id/";
    $file->move(storage_path().$filePath, $fileName);

    return redirect('/users/' . $user->id . '/files')->with('uploaded', true);
}
```

Comment: have you tried to change the session driver?

Comment: didn't try yet... but isn't there any way to disable CSRF just for that form?

Answer (score 2):

Check your `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in php.ini are high enough to support your file size. If `post_max_size` is too low, then the posted input is truncated and the CSRF token is not passed through.

Please DON'T turn off CSRF or rig it to be ignored on certain endpoints...

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
```

see, You have written {{{ csrf_token() }}}

You should write {{ csrf_token() }}

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify CSRF in your form, like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
(...)
```

[Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf)

Answer (score -1):

You can modify your CSRF middleware (which is in `app/Http/Middleware`) to ignore that controller action:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(\Route::is('path/to/form')) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return parent::handle($request, $next);
}
```

Comment: You can't use ``\Route::currentRouteAction()`` in middleware: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28698716/1331425

Comment: @limonte Thanks. Revised to use `Route::is`.

Comment: This is a security hazard! Never disable csrf protection for file upload.

Comment: @UdoE. There are scenarios in which disabling CSRF protection for an upload would be appropriate, like an endpoint intended for use by third-parties via API, where no CSRF token would be available to them. Facebook's API, for example, doesn't have a concept of CSRF protection.

Comment: @ceejayoz, yeah, in that case, the developer trusts the third party API and the user shouldn't be allowed to interact directly with the "insecure" endpoint. Also, It would be rare to find an API making file upload to an application consuming same API. It is usually the other way around, e.g. third party file storage; and in this case, the API ensures security in other ways, e.g. authentication token (not for your users, but for your application).